# Visual Studio 2022 "go to all" don't open the "go to all" dialog, how can I open the correct dialog?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio version:

[image]

And the problem is this: when I click "edit->goto->go to all", that opens a new dialog include two tabs " code search " and " function search".

[image]

Yea, it can search file with "f: filename",  but I don't like it.

I just like the old dialog:

[image]

I think the old one get the correct result faster.

So, I hope to use the old dialog  when I click "go  to all" .

Thank you!!